# What does the police officer say?

Tags: dialogue, rrr

In the movie *RRR*, when Sir Edward announces that there is a threat to the governor and asks the policemen to catch the one who is planning to attack, one of the police officers says, "All right sir, we will apprehend this bugger. Though I would rather roast this swine on a bit of..." and extends his hand asking for the file. What does he say after "a bit of"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this transcript](https://subslikescript.com/movie/RRR-8178634) he says:

> Though I would rather roast this swine
> on a **bed of coals**.

Comment: @CGCampbell fair point, do feel free to edit in future.  We can all improve content here.